# Extracting the frequency with which a counter registers a certain number

Tags: c++

I am using a global counter (integer) that goes in a function, so that I can get the size of a certain event.
On `int main()`, I use the following structure to print the size of the event over many iterations to a file.

```
if (count != 0)
{
     outputFile<<i<<"\t\t"<<count<<std::endl;
     count=0;
}
```

However, I need to extract the no avalanches of that size (register the frequency in which a certain size appears).
Any clues on how I can do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need to know the specific register ?

Comment: Use a std::map<int, std::size_t>, where the key is 'count' and the value is a count of the count? E.g. histogram[count]++;

Comment: @stdcall part of the data I need

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is not clear enough. What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @stdcall apologies for that. My counter gives me a list of the size of the event obtained at each iteration. I now need to get the the frequency of those sizes, just like on a histogram

Comment: Does the histogram need to come out of the C++ program or are you just as happy to post-process the text output to generate the histogram?

Comment: Hi! I will print the data to a file that will be processed using MatLab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have text output that looks like this:

```
1        3
2        49
3        2
4        8
5        2
6        3
7        3
```

You can generate the counts of each like this:

```
sort -nk2 output.txt | uniq -cf1 | sort -nk3
```

Which gives you:

```
2     3        2
3     1        3
1     4        8
1     2        49
```

The first column is the frequency, second column is an arbitrary `i` value where the count occurred, and third column is `count`.  If you plot a bar chart with the third column on the X axis and the first column on the Y axis, you will have a histogram.

Comment: I was actually looking into having that embedded in my code

Comment: actually, your solution will probably suffice - do you how can I save the data generated? thanks

Comment: You mean how to save the output of the `sort` pipeline?  Just add `> histogram.txt` on the end.